# Show tier price on product page only by adding amount

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tierprice

A product has regular tier prices like

- 1 = 10€ (regular price)
- 10 = 5€
- 20 = 4.5€ etc.

Is there a way to show the tier price directly as price on product level?

The same like if user choose a custom options and the price per piece updates.
I mean not as table(!).

It should be shown directly if user adds the amount.

**User adds => 15 => price updates to "4,5€"**

Comment: http://magecomp.biz/demo2/apple-iphone-5c-white-16gb.html   check below add to cart box it somethig like your requirment

Comment: Thx jigs for your idear. I allready found this approach. Unfortunatly it should be without radio boxes. User should only add eg. "20" and than the price should automaticaly change.

Comment: for that functionalyti you used jquery to change price. and disable tier price to display in frontend.